# How do you fully publish a game under your name, under 18?

Tags: legal, monetization, distribution

This has been a week of stress in trying to get things done correctly. It's all tied with keeping things legal and making sure I don't lose out on benefits of any kid. I have just recently finished up a game and now adding the final touches into it so I can make some sort of income.

***I am incredibly sorry if I asked this on the wrong site. I felt that this is still relative to game development because it is the final step of developing your game: preparing yourself for distribution.*** If there is a better site to ask, or if some one has experience in this field please notify me.

**Problems I am having:**

1. **I do not own a company, but just about every service I am trying to make use of is asking for a company name:**

   - I do not know where I can find straight facts about owning, buying, or even keeping up with a name.
   - I am using my full name to publish my works because I read that in similar words, every one was born with a trade-mark known as their name.
   - I can not afford a company in the first place, I read some where that this can cost from 150 and higher. I have no income like said before and the only way I can think about making money as of this time is through my games which apparently requires me to already have at least a couple hundred dollars or more.
2. **I don't know the most efficient and cheapest way to acquire a Tax ID**

   - I don't know where I can read up on this subject, and apparently I am finding that I need an actual company name again - and I'm not entirely sure I can just use my name.
   - I'm not sure if there is an age limit on this, and as I currently stand I don't even have a documented signature.
   - This also costs a couple hundred dollars as I have read and I have no money.
3. **I have no a clue what steps I should be taking for any of this.**

   - I just want to publish games I make without feeling like I'm losing my hard worked time.
   - I want to be able to publish games without feeling I did something illegal.
   - I'd like to be able to have advertisers host on my game so I can make little revenue from people who can't afford buying full games.

**Edit - In Detail:**

- I am currently trying to publish games to the google play store for android entertainment applications.
- I am trying to use the advertisement service known as "mopub" : http://www.mopub.com/.
  This is more like a linker than a direct advertiser that way you can get more benefits of multiple advertisers through your game.
- I am living in the U.S

I don't want to quit making games because of issues like so. I can't publish my games right now if I don't have a legal representative name or a way to make money and not have others steal my rights of owner ship to the games I create.

Comment: may be an idea to add what country you are a resident of and the location of the app store you are trying to monetize through.

Comment: @dav1dsm1th edited in respect to your recommendation.

Comment: It's a little unclear what, exactly, you are asking for. This isn't necessarily off-topic here, but your current question is a *very* broad list of problems. If you're having issues with all of those they may better be asked as separate questions; overly-broad questions or questions about how to get started accomplishing some entire large task are off-topic here (see the [help] for assistance editing your question).

Comment: maybe you better go on gamedev.net or something

Comment: Good question, a pity it was closed. This depends on state law. In most cases you can sell apps and make an income with youtube videos and such, without being taxed, if and only if the income is very small. The definition of "very small" varies. If you make enough to be taxed, you need to have a company, using the "sole proprietorship" model. In that model you basically just tell yourself you now own "Lemony-Andrew Development", and you just created a company - it's legal, look it up on google. Things become more difficult as soon as you cross certain income barriers - look it up by state.

Comment: @Andrew might i suggest you take this to law.se